# creating a setup for a com dll

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation

I am trying to package a com dll in an msi. I want the setup to run a batch file afterwards.
The batch file basically points to the WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 folder and runs the regasm command to register the assembly.

How do I get the setup to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run batch files straight from a VS setup project, but I think you can run scripts that can execute them. Something like this might work:

```
Set s = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
cmd = "yourbat.bat"
s.Run ("cmd /C " & """" & command & """")
Set s = Nothing
```

This might not work on all computers though if they don't have the script host installed already, so it might be better to come up with a non batch file way.

Edit: Just remembered a possibly better way of doing this.

I think it would work to, on your pc run `RegAsm` with the `/regfile` parameter which creates a regfile containing all the settings needed. Then just add that regfile to your setup project and you won't have to run `RegAsm` on the client's computer.

Comment: where do I write that script?

Comment: @daemonkid - in a file and then create a custom action to execute that file. However, please see my updated answer since I think there's a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

A VS Setup project already knows how to register a ComVisible assembly.  Set the Register property of the DLL to "vsdrpCOM".  No additional post-install commands are needed.

Comment: Thanks. The component got registered as well and can be seen in the registry. I have even put the [Guid("")] and [ComVisible(true)] attributes for both the interface and implementing classes in the dll. In the project properties I have also checked 'Register for interop'
However, the calling application still gets this error.
“Unable to Create OLE object”

What could be the problem?

Comment: Well, it is not a registration problem.  Weird message btw, it is not a standard COM error.